# Drag and drop in IE8 and IE9 using kendo upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

In my application i am using kendo Upload.I need to have drag and drop,multiple file slection  functionality.It is working fine with all other browsers except IE8 AND IE9.After some research it is found that hence IE8 AND IE9 doesnt not supports Html5 both the above functionality would not work on these.
Any help. 
The jquery code is as below.

```
 <div style="width:90%">
                <div class="demo-section">
                    <input name="files" id="photos" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div> 
             <script>

                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $("#photos").kendoUpload({

                        async: {
                            saveUrl: "save",
                            removeUrl: "remove",
                            autoUpload: false
                        },
                        showFileList: true
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: What is your question?  As you already stated, this is not possible without the use of ActiveX, Java, or Flash in IE8 or IE9.

Comment: Hi Ray ,
Can you please provide any link for any ActiveX or Flash for making it work in IE8 and IE9.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=drag+and+drop+activex

Answer (score 0):

This Kendo Upload functionality isn't available in IE8 and IE9 because those browsers do not support the HTML5 drag and drop API. You need IE10 at least for file upload via drag and drop.

More info about the supported browser versions can be found here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/upload/supported-browsers